# Matrix Rotation in Python

Tags: python, matrix

In this Program I need to rotate the matrix by one element in clockwise direction.I had done with the code but I have a problem with removing the newlione in the the last row in the given Matrix. In this Program the user has to give the input. The code is

```
def rotate(m):
    if not len(m):
        return
    top=0
    bottom=len(m)-1
    left=0
    right=len(m[0])-1
    while(left<right and top < bottom):
        prev=m[top+1][left]

        for i in range(left,right+1):
            curr=m[top][i]
            m[top][i]=prev
            prev=curr
        top+=1

        for i in range(top,bottom+1):
            curr=m[i][right]
            m[i][right]=prev
            prev=curr

        right-=1
        for i in range(right,left-1,-1):
            curr=m[bottom][i]
            m[bottom][i]=prev
            prev=curr
        bottom-=1

        for i in range(bottom,top-1,-1):
            curr=m[i][left]
            m[i][left]=prev
            prev=curr

        left+=1
        return m

def printMatrix(m):
    for row in m:
        print(' '.join(str(n) for n in row))

n = int(input())
m = []
for i in range(1,n+1):    
    l = list(map(int, input ().split ()))
    m.append(l)
marix=rotate(m)
printMatrix(m)
```

The Test Case is given Below

```
Input               
4 
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 

Expected Output:      
5 1 2 3\n
9 10 6 4\n
13 11 7 8\n
14 15 16 12

Actual Output Which i get:
5 1 2 3\n
9 10 6 4\n
13 11 7 8\n
14 15 16 12\n
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an issue with your `printMatrix()` function, `print()` by defaults adds a newline. You could replace it with below to eliminate the last newline (though I'm not sure why this is so critical):

```
def printMatrix(m):
    print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(n) for n in row) for row in m), end='')
```